# Set default value for WHERE clause for specific columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose I've created a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE stuff(
  a1 TEXT,
  a2 TEXT,
  . . .
  an TEXT,
  data TEXT
);
```

I need to make `SELECT` queries like this:

```
SELECT data FROM stuff WHERE
a1="..." and a2="..." and . . . and an="..."
```

selecting a specific value of data, with **all** `a` values specified.

There are a lot of `a`s that have some value that I consider default.

Is there a way to add some kind of statement to the table or the query that will use some default value for `a`s which are not explicitly constrained in the `where` clause? For example, so that if I don't write `a1="b"` after `where` I get only rows where `a1` is equal to `"b"`, rather than any value, but if I write `a1="c"` I get those.

The default is the same for all `a`s.

The best solution for me would be to bake the default into the table or the database file.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Can you tell me what is unclear?

Comment: Creating a view might help

Comment: Though it is file (non-server) level database, SQLite3, normalization is still recommended. Your table is in wide form and should be in long and have one *a* column, one indicator column for #1 to n, and one value column for text. Saves you from a lot of complex querying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to add some kind of statement to the table or the query
>   that will use some default value for as which are not explicitly
>   constrained in the where clause?

Short answer: No.

Based off of what you said here:

> For example, so that if **I don't write** a1="b" after where

I'm thinking you might be running this query often, maybe even manually, and you want to pass in some different values. If this is indeed the case, you can pass parameters in and use some variables to handle this.

What you can do, is have a `CASE` statement in that `WHERE` to help. Consider the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN %s IS NOT NULL
            THEN a1 = %s
        ELSE a1 = 'b'
        END
    [AND/OR] <other constraints here>
```

Now, the syntax of how you actually do this will vary, based on what you're actually using to execute your queries. Are they being ran from a python program? something in .net? etc etc

Also, you wouldn't have to strictly stick to the `IS NOT NULL` I used there, you could have some other values to do other things with. Up to you.

**EDIT:**

To Shawn's point in the comments, if `%s`, the argument being passed in, is either `NOT NULL` or a legitmate value, then `ifnull()` would be a cleaner alternative for this case statement. Example below:

```
WHERE
    a1 = ifnull(%s, 'b')
```

Comment: I was running these queries by hand for testing, but there will be a php script that does it instead when I'm finished. You are right. It probably is better to handle substitution of default values there. I figured I'd ask anyway in case there is some elegant trick within SQL. I'm not very familiar with SQL.

Comment: @Shawn good catch! I added an edit explaining this cleaner one-liner.